# Safari seems to bundle identical requests when they are dispatched almost at the same time

Tags: angular, http, safari

The upload process in our app is build in such a way that in order to upload a file you first make GET to get the url (this is always the same endpoint, without any params), and then PUT on that  url with the file itself. Im using angular and rxjs. To upload multiple files I use forkJoin from rxjs.

In chrome it works without problems. When i select 4 files, I see 4 GETs and 4 PUTs. But on safari, I see only one GET and then 4 PUTs.

After some investigation it seems to me that safari is able to bundle together the GETs, cache it or reuse - don't really know. But the code is oblivious to it. I put logs after each request and despite only one GET i see 4 logs with the same response but different file name.

There is also a possibility that the server is doing some caching. But that does not explain why in safari's network traffic I see only one request made. When I add random string in a header of the GET all works as supposed and as on chrome.

I'd like to understand how and why it works like that - why chaching and why safari shows only one request.

The code looks roughly like this:

```js
const requestQueue = files.map(file => this.makeGetRequest().pipe(
  map(extractUrlAndAppendFileName(file.name))
));

return forkJoin(requestQueue).pipe(
  defaultIfEmpty([]),
  tap(c => console.log(c)),
)
```

Response headers

```
Response
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Set-Cookie: ...
Transfer-Encoding: Identity
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Request-Id, X-Redirect-Location
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Date: Sat, 05 Feb 2022 14:15:52 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Vary: Origin
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.27
Server: nginx/1.14.2
X-Request-Id: ...8db
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 872
X-RateLimit-Limit: 900
```

Comment: i updated the question. I have no cache-control header, but even if i added it to the request headers it still was not enough. I remember the backend was using some strategy based on request content hashing, I will need to consult with them on monday.

Comment: Maybe Chrome does exactly the same, but you have the dev console open with cache switched off?

Comment: I have exactly same problem. If you check the "Disable Caches" checkbox in the Safari dev tools - everything forks fine and same as in the Chrome, so the problem _clearly_ is in Safari caching behavior. And yes I still have no solution, so would appreciate any help